# Logstash Filter for a custom message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse a bunch of strings in Logstash and output is set as ElasticSearch.

Sample input string is: **2016 May 24 10:20:15 User1 CREATE "Create a new folder"**

The grok filter is:

**match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:user} %{WORD:action_performed} %{WORD:action_description} "}**

In Elasticsearch, I am not able to see separate columns for different field such as timstamp, user, action_performed etc.

Instead the whole string is under a single column "message".

**I would like to store the information in separate fields instead of just a single column.**

Not sure what to change in logstash filter to achieve as desired.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your grok pattern with this, i.e. use `QUOTEDSTRING` instead of `WORD` and it will work!

```
match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:user} %{WORD:action_performed} %{QUOTEDSTRING:action_description}"}
```